# Graylog: How to Import Apache LogFiles into the Graylog server

Tags: graylog

I have a specific need for knowing how to "import" log files I receive from anyone into Graylog.  My need is not about 'sending' or configuring a collector that will be sending logs to Graylog.

I need to know if I can copy a TAR with logs into the graylog and render the content of via the Web UI of Graylog.

I have read many blogs, and I am having difficulty finding guidance for my specific need.

Your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

so far as i know it is not possible to import logs, but you can use fluentd(http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/graylog2) to read log-files.

BUT if you want to send logfiles from apache to graylog try this, add into you apache2.conf the following lines:

```
LogFormat "{ \"version\": \"1.1\", \"host\": \"%V\", \"short_message\": \"%r\", \"timestamp\": %{%s}t, \"level\": 6, \"_user_agent\": \"%{User-Agent}i\", \"_source_ip\": \"%a\", \"_duration_usec\": %D, \"_duration_sec\": %T, \"_request_size_byte\": %O, \"_http_status\": %s, \"_http_request_path\": \"%U\", \"_http_request\": \"%U%q\", \"_http_method\": \"%m\", \"_http_referer\": \"%{Referer}i\" }" graylog2_access
```

and add into you virtualhost file the following lines:

```
CustomLog "|/bin/nc -u syslogserver.example.de 50520" graylog2_access
```

also take a look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/310695/sending-logs-to-graylog2-server

Answer (score 0):

You could try the community editon of [nxlog](http://nxlog.org/products/nxlog-community-edition).  With nxlog you can load up your log files with [im_file](https://nxlog.co/docs/nxlog-ce/nxlog-reference-manual.html#im_file) parse the logs up some and get them into gelf format which should make them easier to search in Graylog2.  If you set `SavePos` and `ReadFromLast` to `False` it will suck in the entire log file anytime you kick off nxlog regardless of when the log happened, or even if it's been entered into Graylog2 before.